# Base method call with default parameters hides other method

Tags: c#-4.0

I understand calling a base method with arguments will default to the method without any default parameters. Great! Fully understandable!

[Resolving Ambiguities with Optional Parameters and Named Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409256/resolving-ambiguities-with-optional-parameters-and-named-arguments)

However, consider this scenario

```
using System;

class Class1 {
    public virtual string method1( string test ) {
        return test;
    }
}

class Class2 : Class1 {

    // Method is hidden!
    public override string method1( string test ) {
        return test;
    }

    public virtual string method1( string test, string test2 = " - this shouldn't be called" ) {
        return test + test2;
    }
}

class Class3 : Class2 {
    static int Main( string[] args ) {

        var c = new Class3();
        string theString;

        theString = c.test1();
        System.Console.WriteLine( theString ); // "Test - this shouldn't be called"

        theString = c.test2( );
        System.Console.WriteLine( theString ); // "Test"

        return 0;
    }

    public string test1() {
        return base.method1( "test" ); // calls base.method1( string, string )
    }

    public string test2() {
        return ( ( Func<string, string> )base.method1)("test"); // calls base.method1( string )
    }
}
```

Clearly the intended behavior of calling the base method should only print out "Test" but it does not and instead calls the method with default parameters. I'm still new to IL but it also shows that it clearly resolves to the method with default parameters.

This essentially hides the method signature method( string ) in child classes.

What exactly is happening here?

Is this a bug in C#? A bug in the compiler?

Are method calls higher up in the generation chain SUPPOSED to have precedence 
over overwritten calls of their child?

Is there something I am just missing?

For the curious, the problem was resolved by using a delegate function

```
( ( Func<string, string> )base.method)("Test"); // prints out "Test"
```

**edit - The code now compiles if copy pasted

Comment: The "code" you have posted does not compile.  Could you post a [mcve] so that your question is clearer?